# Select a resource from each category that should have same available date in java 8 streams

Tags: java

I can get the objects with minimum available date from each category from my list by grouping by group and applying min function on result.

But i need to get the resource from different groups with same available date. It need not be the minimum one.

How can I do that using Java streams?

Even if I can get sql query that would be helpful so I can try building it using Java streams.

```
List<ResourceInformation> list = new ArrayList<ResourceInformation>();
Class ResourceInforation {
      private ResourceGroup resourceGroup;

      private Resource resource;

      private Date availableDate;

      // getters and setters
}
```

Input:

```
|resource_group_id|resource_id|availability_date|
|-----------------|-----------|-----------------|
|      1          |     1     |    10/03/16     |
|      1          |     2     |    10/04/16     |
|      1          |     3     |    10/05/16     |
|      1          |     4     |    10/04/16     |
|-----------------|-----------|-----------------|
```

Output will be the list of ResourceInformation from each resourcegroup with same available date

```
|resource_group_id|resource_id|availability_date|
|-----------------|-----------|-----------------|
|      1          |     2     |    10/04/16     |
|      2          |     4     |    10/04/16     |
|-----------------|-----------|-----------------|
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your data structures, along with expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: I have added the collection which i am trying to work on.

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL?

Comment: I am trying to visualize this problem as single table where i will have resource_group_id,resource_id,available_date columns and i am trying to group by resource_group_id and select the resource_id values which has same availble_date

Comment: I have added some more information like input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Date, List<ResourceInformation>> resourcesByDate = list.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ResourceInformation::getAvailableDate));
```

Produces a `Map` containing an entry foreach date found as the key and the corresponding `ResourceInformation` is a list of values.